# convert JSON string from serializeArray() into sql storeable string

Tags: javascript, json

I am preparing a form elements that are shown like in image https://i.stack.imgur.com/z2L4y.png with add more button, many more such pairs of `textfields` can be added.

Code for elements is as:

```
<td class="answer_choice_<?php echo $question_id ?>" >  
   <span style="float:left; font-size: 14px;">If This Happens...</span> 
   <textarea rows="2" cols="20" name="happens" style="float:left; <?php echo $text_style; ?>" class="answer_choice_<?php echo $question_id ?>"  value=""
></textarea>
  <span style="float:left; font-size: 14px;">I Should...</span>
  <textarea rows="2" cols="20" name="should" style="float:left; <?php echo $text_style; ?>" class="answer_choice_<?php echo $question_id ?>"  value=""></textarea></td>
```

Applying `serializeArray()` to get values as:

```
yellow_flags_ser = $('.yellow_flag_clone_'+qa_id+' :input').serializeArray();

Console log for yellow_flags_ser is :
[Object, Object, Object, Object]
0: Object
name: "happens"
value: "injury"
__proto__: Object
1: Object
name: "should"
value: "call nurse"
__proto__: Object
2: Object
name: "happens"
value: "burn"
__proto__: Object
3: Object
name: "should"
value: "see doctor"
__proto__: Object
length: 4
__proto__: Array[0]
```

I want to make `JSON` string like this `[{happens_value : should_value}, {happens_value : should_value},...]`

Can someone please guide how this can be achieved for above `array of objects.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two steps you need to perform in this:-

1. You need to keep a track of `count` in each pair and when ever creating a new pair then append that count with class/ID.
2. Get all the values of the `textareas` and prepare the `JSON` object

Example JS Code:-

```
var count = 1;
$('#addAnswerChoices').click(function(e){
    count += 1;
    $('<td class="answer_choice_'+count+'" >  
   <span style="float:left; font-size: 14px;">If This Happens...</span> 
   <textarea rows="2" cols="20" name="happens" style="float:left;"    class="answer_choice_'+count+'" id="answer_choice_'+count+'"  value=""
></textarea>
  <span style="float:left; font-size: 14px;">I Should...</span>
  <textarea rows="2" cols="20" name="should" style="float:left;" class="answer_choice_'+count+'" id="answer_choice_'+count+'"  value=""
></textarea></td>').appendTo('#addAnswerChoices');
});
```

And then with JQuery get all the values and prepare the `JSON` oject what you want. :)